# Problems with Newtonsoft serialization in project hosted on IIS

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, iis, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on a project built using ASP.Net Web API 2 and AngularJS. Everything works as expected when I run the project from Visual Studio. But after deploying the project in Local IIS server the API calls giving me this error

```
"The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
```

**YES**  I have the following line in my WebAPIConfig file

```
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

And here's an example API method I am using

```
    // GET api/PatientsAPI
    [ResponseType(typeof(Patient))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetPatients()
    {
        var patients = from patient in db.Patients
                       select new
                       {
                           id = patient.id,
                           name = patient.name,
                           contact = patient.contact
                       };
        return Ok(patients);
    }
```

Comment: what is patient.contact?

Comment: id, name and contact are the columns in Patients table.

Comment: I meant types, which type is contact

Comment: instead of returnig anonymous object..try creating class which will have id , name, contact props and return that class from the method..

Comment: ok, strings, then it should be ok. As Pankaj said, instead of creating an anonymous class create a class with properties.

Comment: @PankajParkar creating new classes for all the objects now when I have everything working in actual project seems overkill to me, maybe I have to try it out in the end, but before that I need to know if there is something else I can do

Comment: @Shuvro what I think you have anonymous object inside you one of three props

Comment: @Gusman yeah someone suggested it, but just wanted to know if there's something else, because this is a large project and this is only a small example, should I not wait for something or go for it already?

Comment: well, hard to tell, try to use a small example as the one you posted, if the behaviour is the same then you know you must go this way

Comment: ok let me try, thanks both of you